# Are there any easy methods of estimating an explicit formula for $\sum_{i=1}^n i^\left(i+1\right)$?

Tags: summation, estimation

I believe the title is pretty clear on what I'm asking for. I guess the part about "easy methods" might be ambiguous. What I mean by "easy methods" is: methods which does not (necessarily) require more than basic one variable calculus.

Comment: You can try integral estimation methods if you have encountered such.

Comment: $x^x$ is a very fast growing function. An estimation that is reasonably accurate in a relative sense will quite quickly be to skip all but the latest term. In other words, to estimate it by it's own derivative.

Comment: @mathreadler . I tried using integral estimation but I dont know if I did it correctly or not. I tried putting a bound on the series by using partial summations and writing $x^{x+1}$ as a taylor expansion. It does not seem like a successful strategy, but I'll post the things I've been working on later this week.

Answer (score 2):

If you are OK with approximate solution, we can start by approximating the sum

$$S(N) = \sum_{k=1}^N k^k$$ by simply skipping all but the latest term.
If we plot the relative errors we get
$$e(N) = \frac{1+2^2+\cdots+ N^N}{N^N}$$

We fit this $e(N)$ to a reciprocal polynomial model of order 4:

$$P(N) = \sum_{k=0}^{4}\frac{c_k}{N^k}$$

(Using [least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares) fit which you will learn in a first linear algebra course)

Gives a pretty good fit up to $N=64$:

[image]

Maybe you can use this observation to build your own even better estimator?

Answer (score 1):

As @mathreadler noted, we can approximate this sum of fast-growing terms with the last term. Obviously, the sum's true value is greater (if $n\ge2$), but what's the relative error? Numerical experiments suggest $\frac{1}{en}$, i.e.$$\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i^{i+1}\approx\frac{n^n}{e}.$$Indeed, incrementing $n$ increases the left-hand side by $n^{n+1}$, and the latter by$$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}-n^n}{e}\approx\frac{n^n}{e}\cdot\left((n+1)\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n-1\right)\approx n^{n+1}.$$

Comment: Thanks @mathreadler .  Very useful answer

Comment: And thank you @J.G. . Though I would like to see exactly how numerical experiments suggest that the relative error is $\dfrac{1}{en}$.

Comment: @VictorGaleano I used [Python](https://repl.it/repls/LightgrayMushyNumbers) (I've rewritten it to give the relative error times $en$; note the result is nearly $1$).